Exercise on Proving Every Cone is Contractible
I'm going through an exercise which seeks to prove that for any space $X$, the cone of $X$, denoted $CX$, is contractible in a somewhat convoluted way. First, the exercise defines the mapping cylinder of a map $f:X\to Y$ as $$M_f=X\times [0,1] \sqcup Y/\{(x,1)\sim f(x)\}$$ It proceeds by the sequence of sub-questions:

Prove the mapping $X\mapsto CX$ defined by $x\mapsto [(x,t)]$ is a homeomorphism onto its image for all $0\leq t<1$.
Show that $CX$ is homeomorphic to the mapping cylinder of the constant map $X\mapsto \{p\}$ for some $p\in X$.
Show that $CX$ is a retract of $CCX$.
Using $(3)$ prove that $CX$ is contractible.


My Attempt
Define the two quotient maps $q_C:X\times [0,1] \to CX$ and $q_{M_f}(-;Y):X\times [0,1]\sqcup Y\to M_f$. I shall suppress the $Y$ argument on $q_{M_f}$ as it should hopefully be clear from context.
For (1), consider the following diagram $$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>f>> X\times [0,1]\\
 & @VV{q_C}V \\
& & CX
\end{CD}$$ The map $X\owns x \mapsto f(x)=(x,t)\in X\times \{t\}=\text{Im}(f)$ is continuous as for any open set $U\in X$, the set $U\times \{t\}$ is open in the product/subspace topology on $X\times \{t\}\subset X\times [0,1]$. Additionally, the quotient map $q_C$ is continuous by definition of the quotient topology. Since $t<1$ both $f$ and $q$ are homeomorphisms as there are no non-trivial equivalences from $q$. So, their composition $q\circ f:X\to (q\circ f)(X)$ is a homeomorphism. Since $(q\circ f)(x)=[(x,t)]$ we are done.
For (2), fix some point $p\in X$. Consider the following diagram, $$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X\times [0,1] @>i>>  X\times [0,1]\sqcup \{p\} @>q_{M_p(\{p\})}>> M_p(\{p\})\\
  @Vq_CVV \\
   CX &
\end{CD}$$ where $i:X\times [0,1] \hookrightarrow X\times [0,1]\sqcup X$ is the inclusion map. As $i$ and $q_{M_p}$ are continuous, their composition is continuous. Additionally, for any $[(x,t)]\in X\times [0,1]$, the composition $q_{M_p}\circ i$ is constant on the fibres of $q_{C}$. Indeed, the only fibre which is not just a point is $q_C^{-1}([(x,1)])=\{(x,1)\in X\times I : x\in X\}$, but $(q_{M_p}\circ i )(q_C^{-1}([(x,1)]))=[p]\in M_p(\{p\})$. By the universal property of $q_C$, this then gives a continuous function $h:CX\to M_p(X)$ such that $h=q_{M_f}\circ i\circ q_C^{-1}$. This $h$ is bijective. Further, for any open set $U\in CX$, $q_C^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X\times [0,1]$ as $q_C$ is continuous by quotient topology definition. Further, $i(q_C^{-1}(U))$ is open in $X\times [0,1] \sqcup X$ by disjoint union topology. Finally, as $q_{M_p}$ is an open map by the quotient topology definition, $q_{M_p}(i(q_C^{-1}(U))$ is open in $M_p(X)$. So our $h$ is also an open mapping. Whence, $h$ is the desired homeomorphism.
For (3), I consider the following diagram, with $p$ now some point in $CX$, $$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
& & &  & CX\times [0,1] @>{[(x,t)]\times \{s\}\mapsto [(x,t(1-s)+s)]}>>  CX\\
  & & & @Vi_1VV \\
CCX @>\tilde{h}>> M_p(\{p\})  @<q_{M_p}<<CX\times [0,1]\sqcup \{p\}  \\
& & & @Ai_2AA \\
& & & & \{p\} @>{p \ \hookrightarrow CX}>>  CX
\end{CD}$$
Where $i_1,i_2$ are the inclusion maps and $\tilde{h}:CCX \to M_p(CX)$ is the homeomorphism.
By the universal property of disjoint union and because all relevant maps are continuous, this gives a continuous map $g:CX\times [0,1]\sqcup CX \to CX$ with the (unique) property that $(g\circ i_1)([(x,t)], s)=[(x,t(1-s)+s)]$ and $(g\circ i_2)(p)=p$. Define the map $r:CCX \to CX$ as $r=g\circ q_{M_p}^{-1}\circ \tilde{h}$. To check this is a well-defined function, we need to show that $g$ is constant on the fibres of $q_{M_p}$. The only non-trivial fibre is $q_{M_p}^{-1}([p])=\{(x,1)\in CX\times [0,1]: x\in CX\} \sqcup \{p\}$. As defined, $g$ is constant on this fibre and is equal to $p$ and so $g$ is a well-defined function. Further, as $g,h$ are continuous and $q_{M_p}$ is an open mapping as a quotient mapping, $r$ is continuous. We can consider $CX$ as a subset of $CCX$ where $(CX)_{CCX}=\{(x,0)\subset CCX: x \in CX\}$. For any $y\in (CX)_{CCX}$, given how I defined the homeomorphism in part (2), $r(y)=y$. Therefore, $r$ is a retraction from $CCX$ to $CX$.
For (4), I want to prove that $CCX$ is contractible, then as $CX$ is the retract of a contractible space, this will prove $CX$ is contractible. To this end, I prove $M_p(\{p\})$ is contractible to the point $p\in CX$. Define a homotopy $H:M_p(\{p\})\times [0,1] \to M_p(\{p\})$ as $$H([x],t)=\begin{cases}[(x_1,tx_2+(1-t))] & \text{ if } x=(x_1,x_2)\in CX\times [0,1] \\
[p] & \text{ if } x=p\in CX \end{cases}$$
Now, $H$ is continuous as the combination of two continuous functions on each set of the disjoint union. Further, $H([x],0)=[x]$ and $H([x],1)=[p]$ since $[p]=[(x_1,1)]$ for any $x_1\in CX$. Therefore, $M_p(\{p\})$ is contractible. Then, $CCX$ is contractible as the homotopy $H':CCX\times [0,1] \to CCX$ defined as $H'(x,t)=\tilde{h}^{-1}(H(\tilde{h}(x),t))$ is a homotopy between the identity on $CCX$ and a constant map. Finally, define a homotopy $H'':CX\to CX$ as $H''(x,t)=r(H'(x,t))$. As $H'(x,0)=\text{id}_{CCX}$, $H''(x,0)=r(\text{id}_{CCX}(x))=x$ as $r(x)=x$ for all $x\in CX$. Further, $H''(x,1)=r(H'(x,1))=r(c)=c$ for some point $c\in CX$ which does not vary with $x$. Therefore, $H''$ is a homotopy from the identity map on $CX$ to a constant map. Therefore, $CX$ is contractible.

My concerns are mainly around parts (2) and (3) and whether I've correctly used the universal properties to prove functions are continuous. I am a bit worried I could have accidently used a function which isn't well-defined at some point. When I draw a picture, it looks obvious but I may have gotten confused in the details. In particular, is $q_{M_p}$ an open map? I think it should be when we endow spaces with their quotient topologies, but I wasn't 100% certain about this. Additionally, I didn't use part (1) in any of the later parts. Have I missed some easy shortcut to prove part (2) or (3)?
